# trying to go through an multi dim array and convert strings to floats

Tags: javascript

I am trying to go through a multi-dim array in javascript to change all the strings that are numbers to floats. I tried using .length function, but I do not think it is working. Is there a way I can use this or do I have to hard-code in limits for i and j? The multi-dim array is in JSON.

```
var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($updatedata, true)); ?>');

for (var i = 0; entries.length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; entries[i].length; j++)
        {
            entries[i][j] = parseFloat(entries[i][j])
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it only 2 levels deep?  Do you have an example of the JSON?  If it's an unknown number of levels deep, you'll need a recursive function.

Comment: yeah it is two levels deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is based off of Nick's (I can't apparently post code in comments):

```
var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($updatedata, true)); ?>');
var entriesArray = array();

for(var obj in entries) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if (!entriesArray[obj]) { entriesArray[obj] = []; }

        entriesArray[obj][prop] = parseFloat(obj[prop]);
    }
}
console.log(entriesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice JSer but I think $.parseJSON returns an object, and they do not have lengths. To iterate through all keys of an object, use the for in syntax. This might work...

```
var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($updatedata, true)); ?>');
var entriesArray = array();

for(var obj in entries) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        entriesArray[obj] = parseFloat(prop);
}
console.log(entriesArray);
```

Comment: It actually depends on the nature of the JSON string, but you have parseInt where it should be parseFloat

Comment: I think this only returns a 1 dim array. How would I be able to make it a two dim array?

Comment: Austen, if you give us some json data it will help us figure it out for you.

@JeremyMiller, most likely correct, will update, ta.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think I figured it out. I changed the part that had entries[i].length and made that into a separate array and just used the .length function on that. I am not sure why that made a difference though. Thanks for the help though.

```
var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($updatedata, true)); ?>');
**var entriesArray = entries[0];**

for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) 
{

    for(var j = 0; j < **entriesArray.length;** j++)
    {
        entries[i][j]= parseFloat(entries[i][j]);

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the solution.  Nick's is closest.  I'll reply to him for a small change.